# iOS - Core Animation - How to set origin when transform property is changed

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, core-animation

I have a `UIView` added as a subview inside its parent view. When the user taps on this `UIView`, I want it to be transformed so it takes the entire screen.

I am trying to do so by changing its `transform` property and I was able to make its size match its parent view but not its position.

I read the Apple documentation and found `frame` cannot be used with `transform`. How do I make its position line up with its parent view?

Also, without using `transform`, is it a good idea to do so by changing its constraints, e.g., `NSLayoutAttributeHeight`?

Comment: did u try view.centre? or try applying affine transform which has both translation and rotation.

Comment: Yes but it didn't seem to work. What I did was: after changing `transform` property, I tried to assign `center` to be the same as its parent view's `center`.

Comment: The `UIView` I was talking about was actually a `UIScrollView`, but in this case it doesn't really matter

Comment: If you use autolayout , this issue might happen. try with out autolayout.

Comment: You still can use Autolayout. I have updated my answer. please check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can simply change the frame after you scale it by transform like this:

```
//i am using 5 for testing purpose
self.backgroundImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(5, 5);

self.backgroundImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.backgroundImageView.frame.size.width, self.backgroundImageView.frame.size.height);
```

OR change the anchor point before the scale:

```
self.backgroundImageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
self.backgroundImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(5, 5);
```

**Update:**
if you use Autolayout in your UIView, the solution might depends on how you set up your constraints, For example, if you set up your image constraints like this:

[image]

I would suggest still using the scale transform, but change the top and left constraint to 0.

or you set up your image constraint like this:

[image]

I would change the center alignment x and y to the center point of the super view

Maybe you can let me know how you set up you constraints, i can do some test for you on my local.

Comment: Warning: If this property is not the identity transform, the value of the frame property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

Comment: Also, I can do this by setting its `frame` without using `transform`. Even ignoring what Apple says, what's the point of using `transform` and then using `frame` again?

Comment: @bohanl i added another possible solution, maybe try change the anchor point to the center? i would simply use the frame changing, if that's a simply action like you described. maybe let me know your concerns, and i can update my answer.

Comment: thanks, I will try that. Also, without using transform, is it a good idea to do so by changing its constraints, e.g., NSLayoutAttributeHeight?

Comment: oh, if you are using auto layout in this case, i would suggest not using the `frame` method then. Would you mind let me know how you set your constraints?